# rtconner laravel/tagging returns empty array

Tags: laravel, tags

```
$article = Post::with('tagged')->first(); // eager load
dd($article->tagNames());

dd($article->tagNames()) returns an empty array
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are there any tags related? Did you try to `$article->tag('Test');` and then to try to access tags?